# TypeError: __call__() got multiple values for argument 'name'

Tags: python, dataset

I converted my dataset to coco format using fiftyone and exported the json file, however when I am loading my dataset into a fiftyone dataset in python in order to visualize it later, I am getting the following error: TypeError: **call**() got multiple values for argument 'name'. Any ideas?

```
import fiftyone as fo
import fiftyone.zoo as foz

# Load raw images into FiftyOne
dataset = fo.Dataset.from_dir(
    "/path/to/image_dir", 
    dataset_type=fo.types.ImageDirectory, 
    name="my_dataset"
)

# Load a model and generate predictions
model = foz.load_zoo_model("ssd-mobilenet-v1-fpn-coco-tf")
dataset.apply_model(model, label_field="predictions")

# Export labeled dataset in COCO format
dataset.export(
    export_dir="/path/to/dataset",
    dataset_type=fo.types.COCODetectionDataset,
    label_field="predictions",
)

dataset = fo.Dataset(
    "/path/to/dataset_dir", 
    dataset_type=fo.types.COCODetectionDataset, 
    name="my_dataset"
)
```

Comment: You pass `name` argument to [`Dataset()`](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/api/fiftyone.core.dataset.html#fiftyone.core.dataset.Dataset) constructor twice. First time you pass it as positional argument and second time you add keyword argument.

Comment: `Dataset.__init__` doesn't take a directory path as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to overwrite the value of the `name` positional argument with the `name="my_dataset"` keyword argument.
For clarification:

```py
dataset = fo.Dataset(
    "/path/to/dataset_dir",                     # this is the positional `name` argument
    dataset_type=fo.types.COCODetectionDataset, 
    name="my_dataset"                           # this is the keyword `name` argument
)
```

Comment: Okay I got it, but how I can solve it?

Comment: @MohammadAliChamass Well, i do not think the Dataset constructor takes any path strings as arguments. Just remove the first positional argument from your function call.

Comment: nope, when I remove it the error moves to : TypeError: _create_dataset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dataset_type'

Comment: The thing is that I got this code from an article and I adjusted it for my own use